# lightswitch search fails when deployed to IIS behind ISA Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, visual-studio-lightswitch

We have successfully deployed a LightSwitch app in a web server IIS 7. The app works perfectly when accessed via the internal IP (http://servername), but when it is done via the external IP (https://www.example.com), the queries don't work. It does fetch ALL data but if something is entered in search fields the query fails, it shows data 
fields with a red X.

Fiddler shows the following info:

```
<LI id=L_defaultr_12>Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact the server administrator. (12217)
```

And the screen looks like this:

[image]

Any suggestion on how to trace this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was caused by the ISA server blocking high-bit characters. When you configure HTTP filtering to block high-bit characters, URLs that contain characters from a double-byte character set (DBCS) or URLs that contain Latin 1 characters are blocked

The solution:

Configure the Web publishing rule so that it does not block high-bit characters. To do this, follow these steps:
    1. Start the ISA Server or Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway, Medium Business Edition Management tool.
    2. Expand ServerName, where ServerName is the name of your ISA Server or Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway, Medium Business Edition computer.
    3. Click Firewall Policy, click the Web publishing rule that you created to publish the Exchange Server computer for access by OWA users, and then click Edit Selected Rule.
    4. Click the Traffic tab, click Filtering, and then click Configure HTTP.
    5. Click to clear the Block high-bit characters check box, and then click OK two times.
    6. Click Apply to update the firewall policy, and then click OK.